# How do I deal with this 'gatekeeper' when I'm in promotion series?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've read about them on some forums (people who will intentionally lose the game just because they don't want you to go to upper tier) and it's really annoying because I've encountered them several times.

One can be the most optimist player could be but when the trolling starts, I just don't know how to deal with it.

Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: I would suggest disable all chat, and communicate only with pings, my cousin does that, he has been in promos for diamond.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The remedy is simple: Be quiet.

It's the first impression. I've seen a pregame-chat in low elo (Silver II) when I was smurfing 2 days ago which were like that (not the real name btw):

```
bashslayer98: hey guys let me mid
bashslayer98: im good at mid
bashslayer98: its promo
bashslayer98: SYNDRA PLZZZZZZZZZZ
bashslayer98: I WANT MID
```

And holy moly - this is annoying. Just because you were good in your last game, it doesn't mean you're good in EVERY game. I played AP Thresh, went 10/0, doesn't mean i can play that at the lcs now. If you start the game like that (or even less annoying, it's still annoying), people are more likely to flame, blame or even troll you because they just think: "Well, we lost anyways. Let's completely troll this annoying guy."

On the other hand, keep your head down ingame. You ever heard the term: "Don't feed the troll."? The same applies here. If you rage in the chat, he gets exactly what he wants. He WANTS to annoy you, he WANTS you to be pissed off and mad. If you just don't react to his actions ingame, he will soon lose interest in his actions and may start playing properly. I had a 0/8 xerath once who was a completey dick in chat, nobody responded to his actions and in the end, he played normally and we won the game. Still reported him after the game though for being a dick, but having such a guy in your team doesn't mean you've lost the game.

But in the end, everything you can do is just ignore and report them. There is no "remedy" or something, just ways not to feed him. Just play and do your best. Pick something with snowball potential if you can (Tip: Learn talon, even a onehanded player could carry with him) or simply do your best.

Comment: Note that 3rd party sites like op.gg tell you who you're in game with, and who is in promo, so keeping quiet only helps against the stupid and/or non-motivated trolls.

Comment: There is nothing you can do if the troll is persistent, the most that can be done is a report. Rising to their bait will only lead to aggravation to yourself and reinforce the trolls behaviour as they receive the rise they were seeking. The best policy is to ignore and do your best, we have all been in these situations from time to time.

Comment: Note that this applies to ANY game. Just keep quiet and do your best. If the troll keeps trolling, at least, you have the "chance" to play against fed opponents and you can try to polish your game. It's easy to do plays if you are fed, less if you are a lot behind.